# Looking for the maximum and minimum of a modulus in the unit disk.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am struggling with something. I need to find the maximum and minimum value of $\left|z^{2 n+m}+i a z^{n+m}+z^{m}\right|$ when $\left| z \right| \leq 1$ (with $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $m,n \in \mathbb{N}_0$).

I have reasoned like this, but I am not sure about my process. We are looking for the maximum value in the unit disk of $\left|f(z)\right|$, where $f(z) := z^{2 n+m}+i a z^{n+m}+z^{m}$. This function $f(z)$ can also be written as:

$$f(z) = z^m(z^{2 n}+i a z^{n} +1)$$

And since $z^m$ is the m-th power of a complex number, it is just escalating whatever is in the parentheses. Therefore, looking for $z$ that maximises $f(z)$ is equivalent to looking for the $z$ that maximises $|g(z)|$, with $g(z) := z^{2 n}+i a z^{n} +1$. Since $g(z)$ is a complex polynomial, it is analytic. And because we are looking at an analytic function in a closed set, the Maximum modulus principle implies that the maxima and minima will be reached in the border of the set (in the unit circle). So, if I find the condition that maximises $|g(z)|$, we can use that to determine the maximum of the original function. I know that all $z$ in the unit circle can be expressed as $z = \text{e}^{i\theta}$, and therefore:

$$g(z) = g(\text{e}^{i\theta}) = \text{e}^{2n\theta i} + ia \text{e}^{n\theta i} + 1$$

And the condition that would make the modulus maxima would be that both of those terms in the sum had the same phase, and this is where I think I am mistaken. I am not very sure how to proceed, or if these reasonings are correct.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

If $m \ge 1$ then clearly the minimum is $0$ (attained at $z=0$) and the maximum is attained on the unit circle; we can assume $n \ge 1$ (as if $n=0$ the function is constant on the unit circle, so there is nothing to prove) and since then $z^n$ covers the unit circle when $z$ covers the unit circle, one needs to find the maximum of $|w^2+iaw+1|$ for $|w|=1$

A simple computation gives:

$$|w^2+iaw+1|^2=(w^2+iaw+1)(\bar w^2-ia\bar w+1)=$$ $$=2+a^2+2\Re w^2 \le 4+a^2$$ with equality for $w=\pm 1$ so the maximum is $\sqrt {4+a^2}$

If $m=0$ (and $n \ge 1$ as $n=0$ gives a constant function), one notes that the quadratic $w^2+iaw+1$ in $w=z^n$ has roots that multiply to $1$ so they are either on the unit circle (this actually happens only for $a=0$), or one is inside, hence the minimum is still zero and the maximum is as above

Comment: What do you mean with "the function is constant on the unit circle and since then $z^n$ covers the unit circle when $z$ covers the unit circle"? What do you mean by covering?

Comment: If $n=0$ the function is constant on the unit circle being clearly just $2+ia$ (edited for clarity); if $n \ge 1$ the function $z \to z^n$ is surjective on the unit circle, so for our purposes it is enough to consider the function in $w=z^n$ which is a quadratic

Comment: Okay, I understand now. Thank you very much!

Comment: happy to be of help

Comment: Sorry, what is the second step of the "simple computation"? I do not understand how that is immediate (sorry, I am tired).

Comment: just multiply term by term using $w\bar w=1$ and notice that the terms with $iaw, -ia\bar w$ cancel out

Comment: Oh man, that's right, I thought this was some identity I wasn't understanding. Thanks!